# What is a good table format for diagramming logical conclusions?

Tags: logic

I am looking for a visual organization format that can help group logical conclusions. Basically, If people are given 3 options, and I am looking to interpret their vote, what is a clean manner of cataloging these items?

Basically, 
 - Option A can entail the numbers 1,2,3
 - Option B can entail the numbers 1
 - Options A, B are not mutually exclusive of each other
 - Option C entails 0 and is mutually exclusive of A, B

Is there a graph or table or other organization method to map visually what the options and their combinations could necessarily entail?

Comment: Maybe PROLOG? ;)

Comment: @JosephWeissman, What visualizer do you use for PROLOG?  I'd love to get my hands on one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of at least two representational systems that would serve your purpose:

1. [Boolean Logic represented in Venn Diagrams](http://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/syll_venn.html).  This certainly adequate for representing the type of example in your question.  However, representation becomes more complicated when you deal with more complex sets of propositions
2. [C. S. Peirce's existential graphs](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_graph).  They are not that well known, but it sounds like they are exactly what you are looking for.